# How to import data from an HTML table to Google Sheets AND include hyperlinked values?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is what I have found so far, but it only imports the values of each cell.  One column(D) will contain values such as a persons name linked to their email address and one column(F) will have a value that says click here which will take you to several different links to register for that specific tournament.  How can I get the script to include the links from the HTML table?
If I put it in JSfiddle it works like a charm.  Is it a limitation of Google Sheets?

```
function getData() {
var queryString = Math.random();
var cellFunction = '=IMPORTHTML("http://www.teamusa.org/USA-Softball/Play-USA-Softball/GOLD-National-Championships/18U-GOLD/Tournament-Information/Qualify?' + queryString + '","table",1)';
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setFormula(cellFunction);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example JSFiddle or public Google sheets example?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Or what is the behavior when this executes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with GoogleSheets, but you may need to include the html anchor in your output. Maybe like this?

```
function getData() {
var queryString = Math.random();
var cellFunction = '=IMPORTHTML("<a href=\"http://www.teamusa.org/USA-Softball/Play-USA-Softball/GOLD-National-Championships/18U-GOLD/Tournament-Information/Qualify?' + queryString + '\">Link name</a>","table",1)';
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setFormula(cellFunction);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained my desired result better.  I'm looking to embed a google sheet that automatically updates with new information as the [home office](http://www.teamusa.org/USA-Softball/Play-USA-Softball/GOLD-National-Championships/18U-GOLD/Tournament-Information/Qualify) updates the table.

Comment: I'm pasting the script into google sheets script editor so that it runs automatically but its not pulling in the links.